# How do I pass a pandas data frame as SQL query filter

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have an excel with input values and I am reading it into a data frame below

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jepaulabi\Documents\Input.xlsx', 
    sheet_name='Sheet1', 
    encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

**country_nm**

```
Germany
Greece
Malaysia
Australia
```

then I want to pass the above data frame (df) into filters of an SQL query like below

```
query = SELECT * FROM country where country_nm in ('Germany', 'Greece', 'Malaysia', 'Australia')
```

and run the query like this

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)

```
x = df.to_string(header=False).split('\n')
country_nm = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in x]
print(country_nm)
```

And then use the above variable in sql query.

Comment: I slightly modified it like this to avoid the Index and it works x = df.to_string(header=False, index=False).split('\n')
input = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in x]
print(input)

Comment: but the SQL is not working ...... SELECT * FROM country where country_nm in ????

Comment: Query=“select * from country where country_nm in (“+country_nm+”)”. You may have to add single quote along with comma while doing join.. and then try printing value of variable country_nm..